# How can I capture the MouseLeftButtonDown event for any child in the form even the children captured this event?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

How can I  capture the MouseLeftButtonDown event for any child in the form even the children captured this event?

Comment: Are you saying you want to capture the MouseLeftButtonDown event no matter where the cursor is on the form, even if it is over another control?

Comment: this is a great question homam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried handling the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event on the form ?